# Accepting Pdf through post request and passing to itext7 pdfreader in c# .net core

Tags: c#, .net, itext7

I am getting a pdf through post request from frontend as an IFormFile form and I want to take that and pass it to pdfreader() in itext7 package. so far i could only pass with the path as string i dont have any path to specify.

Comment: Does the `PDFReader` accept `MemoryStream`? If yes, then pass the data from the formfile. If no, you might have to first upload your server and use the file path.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`Pdfreader`](https://api.itextpdf.com/iText7/dotnet/7.1.11/classi_text_1_1_kernel_1_1_pdf_1_1_pdf_reader.html) accepts [`System.IO.MemoryStream`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.memorystream?view=netcore-3.1), or any generic [`System.IO.Stream`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.stream?view=netcore-3.1), as can be seen in the API documentation: https://api.itextpdf.com/iText7/dotnet/7.1.11/classi_text_1_1_kernel_1_1_pdf_1_1_pdf_reader.html

```
PdfReader (IRandomAccessSource byteSource, ReaderProperties properties)
Constructs a new PdfReader. More...

PdfReader (Stream @is, ReaderProperties properties)
Reads and parses a PDF document. More...

PdfReader (FileInfo file)
Reads and parses a PDF document. More...

PdfReader (Stream @is)
Reads and parses a PDF document. More...

PdfReader (String filename, ReaderProperties properties)
Reads and parses a PDF document. More...

PdfReader (String filename)
Reads and parses a PDF document. More...
```

So you can pass the data from the `IFormFile` form.

Comment: Van Gaasse The IFormFile I am converting it into a byte array for uploading it into cloud storage after that I'm converting the byte array to memory stream like this `Stream stream = new MemoryStream(dataArr);`  its still showing error .

Comment: Ask a new question and add reproducible code to your question. And a stacktrace.